# JSON parsing using clojure

Tags: json, clojure

I'm using Clj Json library to parse JSON data in clojure. How do i access all  the values itertively and print it in a text file?
I have read the JSON. Can someone help me in parsing it and writing it to a text file?

```
def all-records (json/read-json (slurp "file.json")));
(println all-records);
(println (get-in all-records [:entry]))
```

### Update:

Here is a sample json file :

```
{"markers" : [{"point" :new GLatLng (40.266044, -74.718479),
               "homeTeam" : "Lawrence Library",
               "awayTeam" : "LUGip",
               "markerImage" : "images/red.png",
               "information" : "Linux users group meets second Wednesday of each month.",
               "fixture" : "Wednesday 7pm",
               "capacity" : "",
               "previousScore" : ""},
              {"point" :new GLatLng (40.211600, -74.695702),
               "homeTeam" : "Hamilton Library",
               "awayTeam" : "LUGip HW SIG",
               "markerImage" : "images/white.png"]}
```

Comment: Can you show an example file.json with the desired output?

Comment: the file contains name phone number city email etc.. , I need to extract the name and phone number and store it in a text file.

Comment: Eg: abc,9876534267

Comment: the output needs to be coma separated and each row in a new line

Comment: Which clj json library are you using?

Comment: You'll need to add more information to your question, including the exact library you're using to read JSON, the format of the JSON (with an example), the output you want (including an example), and so forth.

Comment: sample json file     :{"markers": [
  {
   "point":new GLatLng(40.266044,-74.718479), 
   "homeTeam":"Lawrence Library",
   "awayTeam":"LUGip",
   "markerImage":"images/red.png",
   "information": "Linux users group meets second Wednesday of each month.",
   "fixture":"Wednesday 7pm",
   "capacity":"",
   "previousScore":""
  },
  {
   "point":new GLatLng(40.211600,-74.695702),
   "homeTeam":"Hamilton Library",
   "awayTeam":"LUGip HW SIG",
   "markerImage":"images/white.png"
] }

Comment: i need to extract the homeTeam and awayTeam and print it row wise in a text file

Answer (score 4):

If you put the json in a file like so:

```
{"markers" : [{"point" :new GLatLng (40.266044, -74.718479),
  "homeTeam" : "Lawrence Library",
  "awayTeam" : "LUGip",
  "markerImage" : "images/red.png",
  "information" : "Linux users group meets second Wednesday of each month.",
  "fixture" : "Wednesday 7pm",
  "capacity" : "",
  "previousScore" : ""},
  {"point" :new GLatLng (40.211600, -74.695702),
    "homeTeam" : "Hamilton Library",
    "awayTeam" : "LUGip HW SIG",
    "markerImage" : "images/white.png"]}
```

and then write a little code:

```
(ns ...
  (:require [cheshire.core :as cc] ...))

(def json-data (slurp "resources/sample.json"))

(defn json->clj [arg]
  "Shortcut to cheshire.core/parse-string"
  (cc/parse-string arg true))  ; true => keywordize-keys

(pprint (json->clj json-data))
```

you get an error

```
Error refreshing environment: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: 
Unrecognized token 'new': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or NaN
```

The problem is the 2 occurrances of `new GLatLng (40.266044, -74.718479)` in the JSON data. JSON data is ***only*** data, like strings & numbers. You cannot have a function call (in this case a constructor call) embedded in the JSON.

Comment: i have read the json file now i need to traverse through the json using get-in and extract values out of it